# Button tag not showing in IE7 (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, button, input, internet-explorer-7, submit

Seems to be working in every other browser, but for some reason I can't get the button to show up in IE7.

Here's part of the HTML, CSS and JQuery:

```
<div class="bookit"><a>Bookable locally</a></div>

    button {
        margin:auto;
        padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #btnSubmit {
        z-index:1000;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .bookit a {
        display:none;
    }

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".bookit").appendTo($("div" + toopen + " > div > div.costs"));

        $("#dp1").appendTo($("div" + toopen + " > div > div.costs > div.bookit"));
        $("#txtAltDate").appendTo($("div" + toopen + " > div > div.costs > div.bookit"));
        $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").appendTo($("div" + toopen + " > div > div.costs > div.bookit")).text("Book now...");

        $('.costsdetails').show();
        $('.bookingdetails').hide();
        $(".excursionSubmitButton").hide();
        return false;
        });

    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.dropdown a').click(function () { 

        if ($(this).attr("name") == "local") {
            $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").hide();
            $(".bookit").show();
        } else {
            $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").show();
            $(".bookit").hide();
            pickable =  $(this).attr("name").split(",");
             closedDays;
        }

    });

    $(".datepicker").each(function() {

        $(this).datepicker({

            showOn: "button",
            buttonText: "Book now...",
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function(date) { 

            $(this).parent().find('button').text("Change date..."); // Change words on datepicker button

        })

    });

</script>
```

Comment: your javascript code is not complete.

Comment: Is there any chance of a minimal demo that reproduces your problem, on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Have update the original post, hopefully it will be easier to understand what I am trying to do by looking at the JS Fiddle. I haven't included the entire jquery code, mind.

Comment: Missed out some jquery, updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/UneGn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i've experienced with IE is that it doesn't like trailing commas after you close `}`

Just have a look through your code and make sure that there isn't any.

If not you may need to give us some more information about the javascript error you receive.

Answer (score 0):

in your css you hide

```
.bookit a
```

and in the jquery you do

```
$(".bookit").show();
```

This should also be

```
$(".bookit a").show();
```